# Is there a way to run JavaScript code via a shortcut within Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Is there a way (extension or something build-in) in Firebug to create a shortcut that runs a piece of JavaScript (e.g. a function)?

For instance, I want to delete the local storage and do a reload each time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

Comment: I am using Clear Cache 1.4 for this. Here is a [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearcache/) for you

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't remove the localStorage..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently (Firebug 2.0.1) cannot bind a keyboard shortcut to JavaScript code you entered within Firebug.

Though you at least have the possibility to save aliases for URLs containing scripts as described in "[How to inject JavaScript snippet via Firebug on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993438/how-to-inject-javascript-snippet-via-firebug-on-page-load/24093223#24093223)". This at least allows you to store specific functionality and call it again later via the [`include()` command](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include).

There are also [some feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list?can=1&q=id%3D6951%2C6303%2C6201%2C2874) targetting easy code snippet execution. You may want to [create a new request](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry?template=User%20enhancement%20request) for allowing to reference these snippets via a shortcut.